# Access SQL syntax error (missing operator) when query contains multiple JOINs

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, inner-join, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to make an UPDATE query (using Access 2013) that calculates a value based on values stored in two separate linked tables.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
UPDATE tblCreatures 

INNER JOIN tblRole ON tblCreatures.Role = tblRole.RoleName 
INNER JOIN tblRank ON tblCreatures.Rank = tblRank.RankName

SET tblCreatures.HP = ((tblRole.Level_0_HP + (tblCreatures.NominalLevel * tblRole.BonusHP)) * tblRank.HP_Multiplier);
```

This gives me a syntax error, saying

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "tblCreatures.Role = tblRole.RoleName INNER JOIN tblRank ON tblCreatures.Rank = tblRank.RankNam"
```

(and yes, it cuts off at RankNam, not RankName)

Testing things out, if I remove one of the inner joins (and thus all references to that table) then the update query works just fine, but if I put the other inner join back in, I continuously get this same syntax error.  I don't understand why... I should be able to put two inner joins next to each other, shouldn't I?

Comment: Again, this update works perfectly fine if I take out the second inner join.  It's only when I use both inner joins that I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL requires parentheses when a query contains multiple JOINs. If you build the query in Access' query designer it will look like this (reformatted for clarity):

```sql
UPDATE 
    (
        tblCreatures 
        INNER JOIN 
        tblRole 
        ON tblCreatures.Role = tblRole.RoleName
    ) 
    INNER JOIN 
    tblRank 
    ON tblCreatures.Rank = tblRank.RankName 
SET tblCreatures.HP = ((tblRole.Level_0_HP + (tblCreatures.NominalLevel * tblRole.BonusHP)) * tblRank.HP_Multiplier);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I even tried parenthesis, but I didn't include tblCreatures inside the parenthesis.  I wonder why it requires that... but regardless, this worked like a charm.  Thanks for illuminating a weird quirk of Access's syntax for me!